# If monads come from adjunctions what do graded monads come from?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, monads

Basically can you generalize adjunction to "graded adjunction?"

I have a hunch you would end up with something similar to some linear logic stuff. My thoughts are you can use monads for effect systems and you can use adjunctions for effect systems (call by push value is an example) and you can use graded monads for effect systems so you ought to be able to use "graded adjunctions" for effect systems. I feel if you generalize that much you would end up with some sort of linear logic stuff.

Comment: See §3 here https://www.irif.fr/~mellies/papers/fossacs2016-final-paper.pdf

Comment: @fosco thank you. So suppose you have a monad $T$ graded by a set of effects used (input, output, exceptions, etc..) If I understand this right you'd decompose the monad into an adjunction $T_s(A) = U (s \otimes F(A)) $ and reading input would become something like a map $\text{getLine} : 1 \rightarrow \{\text{input}\} \otimes F(\text{string})$. But a strict action seems a bit awkward from an effects system POV. You want a definitional equality like $\{\} \otimes A = A$. Not a deal breaker but seems awkward to work around with setoids.